# can't select the shape in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003, shapes

I have a problem today that is the first time I meet it. I have opened an old file (this file from 2005), then this contain of flowchart which made from excel's autoshape.
Then I want to make some revision for this file, But I have a problem when I want to select this shapes.

Before select (click the shape), I'm highlighted the shape using my mouse but my kursor icon change into (stop icon). So, this shapes can't be highlighted or selected.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have you considered that your workbook is damaged in some way? Sometimes copying the whole sheet to a new workbook helped people. Also have a look at microsofts advices for [repairing Workbooks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820741/en-us)

Comment: Sounds like the object, sheet or workbook is locked, protected or is read only.

Comment: workbook show `[group]`

Comment: @nunu: Can you upload your workbook?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have more than one worksheet selected at the same time.  You won't be able to select shapes when you have more than one worksheet active.

Comment: Aha, that's why I keep finding changes in my worksheets I don't remember making.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen Excel 2013 get into a state in which it thinks multiple sheets are selected even though there is no visual indication that that is so.  In that case, just right-click the active sheet's tab and select **Ungroup Sheets**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Excel for Office 365 (Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13001.20266) 32-bit). I was viewing the file in the browser. The solution was to open it in desktop Excel.